# SyntaxException with Neo4j LOAD command

Tags: csv, neo4j, load, uri, filenames

I'm using neo4j 2.1.2 for windows
I was attempting to use Neo4j's load csv command but I get the following error...

```
neo4j-sh (?)$ load csv with headers "file:../test/unclaimed.csv" AS csvLine
 MERGE (o:Original_Transaction_Number { value: csvLine.OTN })
 MERGE (i:Institution {name: csvLine.Institution })
 MERGE (i)<-[:TRANSACTION_OF]-(o)
 ;


SyntaxException: Invalid input 'l': expected <init> (line 1, column 1)
"load csv with headers "file:../test/unclaimed.csv" AS csvLine"
 ^
```

infact I get the same error by just entering load

```
neo4j-sh (?)$ load ;
==> SyntaxException: Invalid input 'l': expected <init> (line 1, column 1)
==> "load "
==>  ^
```

Could anyone explain what's happening?

(EDIT:)->(FIXED)->(THE PROBLEM)

Combination of issues here.

1. I had earlier tried upgrading to 2.1.2 be simply extracting files to 2.0.3 folder - fixed - thanks @Stefan
2. Fixing 1. and prefixing with **"cypher 2.1"** (thanks @Michael) gave more informative error "SyntaxException: Invalid input '"': expected whitespace, comment or FROM (line 1, column 23) - **I was missing the FROM keyword**
3. After getting many "LoadExternalResourceException: Couldn't load the external resource at: file:../test/unclaimed.csv"  and many variants of "file://c:/nosql/test/" etc **i finally** figured that the syntax for accessing a local file on windows is simply **"file:c:/nosql/test/unclaimed.csv**" and not file:// as might be inferred from examples on http://neo4j.com/docs/2.1.2/cypherdoc-importing-csv-files-with-cypher/ or anyone familiar with URI schema

Thanks folks

Comment: that is not expected. Are you sure you're running Neo4j 2.1.2? Check using `neo4j-sh (?)$ dbinfo -g Kernel KernelVersion`.

Comment: can you try to prefix it with `cypher 2.1 load ...`

Comment: Huge thanks for the note about the Windows file path format!  I kept adding the file:// over and over until I saw this post.