# Specify address of CSV file for importing to Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I have a CSV file located in my hard disk, I want to import it to neo4j with load CSV command but I don't know how do I specify the address of CSV file in cypher query.

Comment: http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/cypherdoc-importing-csv-files-with-cypher.html

Comment: be aware that `file:` URLs are always seen from the server and not from the client's view to the world. So `file:` requires to copy the csv file to the Neo4j server.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this page [CSV-Cypher-Import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24438083/neo4j-csv-cypher-import)

You must use windows file access syntax.