# Error on import data neo4j

Tags: graph, neo4j, analytics

On windows 7, I can't upload CSV files. 
[image]
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Neo4j csv cypher import](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24438083/neo4j-csv-cypher-import)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should load file only from import folder further so like

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///coursera/data/test.csv" as line
do sth
```

Comment: i tried it , but i have mentioned error                                                   Couldn't load the external resource at: file:/C:/Users/mshendi/Documents/Neo4j/default.graphdb/import/coursera/data/test.csv

Comment: then you should put the file there in the default.graphdb/import folder so it will work

Comment: kindly be informed  i` m using  windows 7

Comment: put the file in `c:/programfiles/neo4jCE3.1.1/import/test.csv`
and run `LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///test.csv" as line`

Comment: kindly i used the mention code                                                                          LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///C:/Users/mshendi/Documents/Neo4j/default.graphdb/import/coursera/data/test.csv" AS line
MERGE (n:MyNode {Name:line.Source})
MERGE (m:MyNode {Name:line.Target})
MERGE (n) -[:TO {dist:line.distance}]-> (m)

Comment: but still have problem                                                                        Couldn't load the external resource at: file:/C:/Users/mshendi/Documents/Neo4j/default.graphdb/import/Users/mshendi/Documents/Neo4j/default.graphdb/import/coursera/data/test.csv

Comment: yes because you should use
`LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///coursera/data/test.csv" as line`

Comment: the file:/// starts from your import folder

Comment: dear i`m working on windows 7 , not on MAC , the syntax you have mentioned i think it for MAC

Comment: LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///coursera/test.csv" as line
MERGE (n:MyNode {Name:line.Source})
MERGE (m:MyNode {Name:line.Target})
MERGE (n) -[:TO {dist:line.distance}]-> (m)                                                         this work fine , thanks a lot dear